# how to prevent double trigger between touch and mouse events

Tags: html, canvas, touch

I have built a jquery html5 canvas sketching app that accepts mouse events for desktop (pen tablets just use mouse events).  I would also like to allow drawing with the finger on iphone, ipad, andriod devices as a mobile web enabled app.  Since mobile devices also trigger mouse click events on their own: Does this mean that I should detect the type of browser and replace all mouse bindings with touch bindings in order to prevent events from double firing?

Here is a stupid example:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1600px" height="1600px" style="border:1px dashed gray;background-color:white;">
    </canvas>

    <script>

    function brushStart() {
      $('#myCanvas').css('background-color','blue');  
    }
    function brushEnd() {
      $('#myCanvas').css('background-color','red');   
    }
    function brushMove() {
      $('#myCanvas').css('background-color','yellow');  
    }

    $('#myCanvas').bind('mousedown', brushStart);
    $('#myCanvas').bind('mouseup', brushEnd);
    $('#myCanvas').bind('mousemove', brushMove);
    $('#myCanvas')[0].addEventListener('touchstart',brushStart,false);
    $('#myCanvas')[0].addEventListener('touchend',brushEnd,false);
    $('#myCanvas')[0].addEventListener('touchmove',brushMove,false);

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following to do what you're looking for:

```
$("#myCanvas").bind("touchstart mousedown", function (event) {
    var e = event.originalEvent;
    e.preventDefault();

    startX = (e.targetTouches != undefined) ? e.targetTouches[0].screenX : e.offsetX;
    startY = (e.targetTouches != undefined) ? e.targetTouches[0].screenY : e.offsetY;

});
```

A couple of points -- you need to access the originalEvent in jQuery in order to work with targetTouches. Also, as I'm sure is apparent, you can substitute any property pair you need for offsetX/Y for the mouse events.